# How do I search for packages using yarn?

Tags: package-managers, yarnpkg

How do I search for packages with yarn?
I want to get a list of results that have the search term in the name of the package as well as in descriptions (similar to how various utilities work like `npm search`, `apropos`, `apt-cache search`).

I tried `yarn info <pkg>`, but this gave a bunch of json data that was limited to just that package.

Using `yarn help` and duckduckgo was educational, but still didn't answer how to do this.

Answer (score 26):

there is no command for showing the **tabular data**  format of package information

if you what more information about the packages you can try **below commands** you will get more information

```
yarn info package

yarn info package  --json

yarn info package@version

yarn info package description

yarn info package time

yarn info package readme
```

Comment: It turns out I don't care about tabular data at all. I just want a list of possible packages, like what ``npm search`` gives you.

Comment: yarn search is not available  https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/778

Answer (score 22):

I came here via google and none of the answers really explained anything about **WHY** search was "missing", so I dug in a bit.

From the Yarn dev's github issue tracker, [this exact topic was brought up](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/778#issuecomment-253146299):

> kittens commented on Oct 12, 2016
>
> We've deliberately decided not to add these sorts of commands to Yarn. There's a lot of them that don't actually see much use and the maintenance burden isn't really worth it. If the functionality of the commands is so simple (just opening a browser) then you can just do it yourself. Thanks for the report!

So there you go, **it has been intentionally not included and there are currently no plans to include it.**

As others have said, you can either use `npm`'s search as both yarn and npm fetch from the same list of packages, or you can use a web-based solution:

- https://www.npmjs.com/
- https://www.npms.io/
- etc

Hope this helps others save a few minutes in their quest for an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I use [npms-cli](https://simpleit.rocks/how-to-search-packages-using-yarn/):

Install:

```
yarn global add npms-cli
```

Then you will have available `/usr/bin/npms` and can search like: `npms search <desired package>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn has a website which has information and a detail page for every package in the registry. It’s available on [yarnpkg.com/en/packages](https://yarnpkg.com/en/packages) and provided by [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com).

Since the npm and Yarn registry are the same, you can also use every tool that shows this data, like [npms.io](https://npms.io) or similar.

---

Fair disclosure: I work for Algolia and am in charge of the search page of Yarn.

Comment: That page is broken (minified react issue)

Comment: @vp_arth, can you open an issue with repro? I don’t see any errors now :) GitHub.com/yarnpkg/website